# Illustrator artboard limitations

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to complete an artwork sized 22.5 feet x 15 feet in Illustrator but can't because Illustrator has  limitations on artboard size. How can I circumvent these limitations?

Comment: Adobe has not been on top of this for a few years now, don't expect them to any time soon, the only solution is "workarounds" which in print sometimes is the cause for reprints when accuracy in print is a must.

Comment: I've been doing print design for a loooong time, mostly in the past using Adobe products, and have ***never*** had trouble with designing *to a **specified** scale* and having it printed correctly. That said, I can tell you I just created an artboard in Affinity Designer that was 22.5 ft by 15 feet as a test (had to enter in inches values) and it saved and worked without trouble.

Answer (score 4):

*You should ask your print house*, but it's probably fine to deliver artwork at 1:10 scale.

So I would simply set up my document to 2.25 feet x 1.5 feet and tell the print house to print it ten times larger.

Beware that any images of course will be printed at 1/10 of the effective resolution you deliver them in.

Comment: All content in the artwork is in vector so will be not a problem for the resolution. Can i ask you which format is better to save please for printing? Should i use .pdf?

Comment: Pdf is always the best option for print, since it can contain both vector graphics and images.

Comment: @Wolff other formats can not?

Comment: @joojaa, I didn't say it was the only one. I would argue though, that in the printing business (offset and digital) PDF is the preferred format. AI files and InDesign packages can of course be used, but there is a greater risk of misunderstandings, missing links, missing fonts etc. I've worked with a t-shirt printer who prefers AI files because he prints directly from Illustrator. Every other print house I know (including my own) use a workflow that only accepts PDFs. So if a customer delivers an AI file I need to spend time creating a PDF of the correct pages with bleed etc.

Comment: My point was that those are not the reasons to use PDF the reasons you outlined now are.

Comment: Point taken @joojaa. To be honest, I didn't even think of alternatives to PDF before you commented :-). I was focused on advising against using a raster format.

Answer (score 0):

Easy workaround as Woff said you make it 10 times smaller but export it at 720-1500 ppi. Afterwards in photoshop you resize it from 720 to 72 or 1500 to 150 (without resample). You can even make an action for photoshop to flatten and resize to apply that in a batch.